# Mutator is not working with bulk insertation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, mutators

I am trying to insert multiple record in laravel by using `Order::insert($orderArray);` 
I have made a mutator that is

```
public function setOrderDetailAttribute($value)
{
    if ($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['order_detail'] = serialize($value);
    }
}
```

mutator is not working. But when i insret single record by using `Order::create($orderArray[0][0]);` Then mutator is working fine. My question how i can use mutator with insert function or bulk insertation.

Comment: too sad i didnt get an answer.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `Order::insert($orderArray);` , it doesn't touch Eloquent in fact. 
It just proxies the call to Query\Builder@insert() method.

So I think the mutator can't be used in that way.

Comment: so how can i do bulk insertation wih mutator? please any suggestions . can i do it without using forloop

Comment: insert is method of Query\Builer class, It save raw data. so I think we can not use with mutator here. You need to format your data before insert.

Comment: @UmarAkbar you could override the `insert()` method to filter your values through the mutators. One option would be creating `Order` instances with `new Order`, then passing the data with `fill()` method and getting it back with `toArray()`. if you don't want your accessors to interfere, you could play around with `$this->attributes` and see waht u can do.

Answer (score 0):

As @Chung has pointed out using insert() to do mass update would "just proxies the call to Query\Builder@insert() method" which is not a "pure Eloquent" way of saving records to DB.

What you need to do instead is:

```
foreach( $orderArray as $item ) {
     Order::create($item);
}
```